# CsvHelper Map Constant Value

Tags: c#, csv, mapping, csvhelper

I have a question about the CsvMapper for .NET.
I'm using the class mapper to map an object into a csv file like this:

```
Map(x => x.ProductId).Name("ProductId");
```

this works fine but how can I write a constant value into a column i declare? In every Row should be this static value.

I tried

```
Map(x => "constant value").Name("Constant Value Column")
```

but it throws an exception "Not a member access"

I need this because the csv File has to be uploaded for an import to another system which needs a defined column structure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question and probably you have found a solution, I am posting this answer for coming searchers.

you may just using below line to map a constant value on output csv file

```
Map().Index(10).Constant("your constant value");
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Map` is used to map existing CSV columns to your class members either by name or index.  Since this seems like a value you are adding, it wont exist in the CSV and should be `Ignored` by the mapping; the value would be set by your class:

```
class SampleItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public int Group { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime ItemDate { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string ConstVal { get; set; }

    public SampleItem()
    {
        ConstVal = "Ziggy";
    }

    public class SampleItemMap : CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvClassMap<SampleItem>
    {
        public SampleItemMap()
        {
            AutoMap();
            Map( m => m.ConstVal).Ignore();
        }
    }
}
```

Since the CSV columns are in the same order as the properties, this can use `AutoMap`.  The `ConstVal` properties is `Ignored` because it originates in the class.

```
List<SampleItem> sList = new List<SampleItem>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Temp\sample.csv", false))
using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(sr))
{
    csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
    csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<SampleItem.SampleItemMap>();

    sList = csv.GetRecords<SampleItem>().ToList();
    dgv2.DataSource = sList;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry for my inartfully expressed question, but I want to write from an Enumerable of objects to a csv file. Some fields needed at the csv file (the constant values) do not exist at the object, so I want to create constant values for writing to csv. The constant values are necessary because the csv file I want to create has to be uploaded to another system. Maybe I could just add constant properties to the object, but that wouldn't be a clean solution for me because my objects to export are part of entity framework code first database.

Comment: I am not sure input vs output matters - if the data doesnt exist it doesnt exist.  If you dont want to create a new class for the csv output, you could use a `ToCSVString()` method which formats the members and adds some literals to the the string as needed `return String.Format("{0}, {1}, ziggy, {2}..."`