# How can I add my CSVHelper delimiter to the beginning of each record

Tags: c#, .net, csvhelper

I am using CSVHelper to create a pipe delimited file that has dozens of objects that are being mapped and written. The requirement includes having the pipe character at the beginning and end of each record so the output would look something like this:

`|SYSTEM|5|123456789|A003|07/08/1992 00:00|00301fJ|11/14/2023 08:47|33291|11/14/2023 08:47|33291|`

`|SYSTEM|7|123456789|B005|555-55-5555|00301fJ|11/14/2023 08:47|33291|11/14/2023 08:47|33291|`

`|SYSTEM|9|123456789|B005||CA|01/01/0001 00:00|00301fJ|11/14/2023 09:22|33291|11/14/2023 09:22|33291|`

`|SYSTEM|11|123456789|C1234||CA|00301fJ|11/14/2023 09:22|33291|11/14/2023 09:22|33291|`

`|SYSTEM|13|123456789|H003|||||||00301fJ|11/14/2023 09:22|33291|11/14/2023 09:22|33291|`

I have tried to manually add the leading and trailing pipe character manually like this:

```
foreach(var record in myList)
{
    csv.WriteField(config.Delimiter, shouldQuote: false);
    csv.WriteRecord(record);
    csv.WriteField(config.Delimiter, shouldQuote: false);
    csv.NextRecord();
}
```

but that duplicates the pipe characters. Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can do this?

Comment: Rather than repeating the delimiter at the beginning and the end, what you really have is an empty field at the beginning and an empty field at the end.

Comment: ^^ see this comment. On your model, add string property "start" and string property "end" under specific mapped index. Other than that, you can do it in the c# line by line - text file operation

Comment: Building on the suggestion of @madreflection, you could map a constant empty string property at the beginning and end of each row.  See [CsvHelper Map Constant Value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38956117) for how.

Comment: I was hoping there was something I was unaware of in CSVHelper but I may have to go with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have applied suggestion from comment to fix the issue.

You could fix by replacing `config.Delimiter` used by `string.Empty`.

**Modified Code:**

```
foreach (var record in myList)
{
    csvwriter.WriteField(string.Empty, shouldQuote: false);
    csvwriter.WriteRecord(record);
    csvwriter.WriteField(string.Empty, shouldQuote: false);
    csvwriter.NextRecord();
}
```

Comment: This was a simple fix to the issue.